# VBA select case multiple ranges

Tags: vba

I am trying to figure out how to use the select case for the problem below.

1. In cell A1 I will have the text "white" or "black"
2. In cell B1 is a number
3. In cell C1 is the result i am looking for to be shown

   ```
   If A1=white and B1<2 then C1=25
   If A1=white and B1>=2 then C1=49
   If A1=black and B1<2 then C1=14
   If A1=black and B1>=2 then C1=30
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
Select Case True
 Case Range("A1") = "white"  And Range("B1") < 2: Range("C1")=25
 Case Range("A1") = "white"  And Range("B1")>=2: Range("C1")=49
 Case Range("A1") = "black"  And Range("B1") < 2: Range("C1")=14
 Case Range("A1") = "black"  And Range("B1")>=2: Range("C1")=30
End Select
```